# What do you call a person who always has what you need?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nicknames

For example I seem to always have what everybody needs/wants, from Advil to bobby pins to a deck of cards. What would you call me?

Comment: _Deep pockets?_

Comment: Colloquially?  The go-to guy.

Comment: I would second go-to guy.

Answer (score 3):

I would just say somebody is **ready for any occasion** or **well-stocked**.

I think the simplest term is **prepared**.

> to make yourself or someone else ready and able to deal with a future
>   even

*Boy scouts* are always prepared and if this person just had 100s of items and was a woman you could go with *Mary Poppins*.

Answer (score 2):

They are often called as *[lifesaver](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lifesaver)*.

> something or someone which provides help that is badly needed

---

They might be called a *supplier* or a *ready supplier*.

There is a military term called *provisioner* also.

Answer (score 1):

A **friend in need** is a friend indeed. If what you need is a year's worth of freeze-dried provisions or enough ammunition to topple the government of a small country, they're probably a **[prepper](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/prepper)**.

Answer (score 0):

superhero

example : my dad is my superhero

Answer (score 0):

A *shopkeeper*.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​